# Owin claims - Add multiple ClaimTypes.Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I have an application in which users can be assigned the following roles:

- SuperAdmin
- Admin
- User

One user may have assigned two or more roles, eg. both SuperAdmin and User. My application uses claims, and therefore i want to authenticate user roles through claims too. like:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

Unfortunately, i dont know how i can add multiple roles to my ClaimTypes.Role. I have the following code:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User", "Admin", "SuperAdmin")
        },
            "ApplicationCookie");
```

As you can see, i tried to add more roles for the sake of illustrating, but obviously its done in a wrong way, and therefore doesn't work. 
Any help is therefore much appreciated.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

A claims identity can have multiple claims with the same ClaimType. That will make it possible to use the **HasClaim** method for checking if a specific **user  role** is present.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"), 
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"SuperAdmin")
    },
        "ApplicationCookie");
```

Comment: why did you hard coded the values? consider the case in which an applicationuser has a property role of list type then how would you solve?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI if ```roles``` are in a list you can do ```foreach (var role in roles) claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));```

Answer (score 8):

@Parameswar Rao explained well but in case of dynamic roles

For example a user object already has property role of type list like

[image]

then using [localfunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

```
  ClaimsIdentity getClaimsIdentity()
                {
                    return new ClaimsIdentity(
                        getClaims()
                        );

                   Claim[] getClaims()
                    {
                        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                        foreach (var item in user.Roles)
                        {
                            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item));
                        }
                        return claims.ToArray();
                    }

                }
                    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {


                        Subject = getClaimsIdentity()
                    }
```