# Claim based authorization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I have a user with the following claims:
`role: ["Admin","Tester"]`

I want a controller method to only be accessible with the role claim value 'Admin'.
For that I have added a policy like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("role", "Admin"));
        });
```

and added the `[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]` attribute on top of my controller method.

Unfortunately, when starting the application, the user does not have access.

If I remove the role `Tester` from his claims so that he only has Admin (`role: "Admin"`) and it isn't an array anymore, he does have access.

As I understood, the policy should check like a "contains", but somehow that doesn't seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried ```policy.RequireRole()```

Comment: Good call, I hadn't tried that yet. Unfortunately it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: this might be worth a read https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/role-based-and-claims-based-authorization-in-aspnet-core-using-policies-hands-on

Comment: Can you show us how you're adding claims to your users, code like: `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin", ClaimValueTypes.String);`

Answer (score 0):

You might not understand it correctly. A claim has up to six parameters, and each parameter corresponds to a different function, not an array. This is source code.

```
public Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject);
```

You can add these claims one by one.

```
    var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                
                new Claim("role","Tester"),
                new Claim("role","Admin"),
            };
```

The claims can store multiple same ClaimTypes.

[image]

Also, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791416/owin-claims-add-multiple-claimtypes-role).

Comment: yes that's how I have it, I've added multiple roles like this: `new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Tester"),`

Comment: no, it didn't answer my question, I had it like this from the beginning and it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, but it is impossible to realize the multiple roles as you describe. Except this method, what methods can you accept to achieve? Can you describe it more clearly?